# want to have a default wipe out text example with java-script only

Tags: javascript, html

Hi all i want an example of html which will have default text and when user clicks on text box it will disappear and i want it to be in javascript only. Below is my html code how could i use javascript here its an urget. So please all java-script expert i need your help

```
<html>
  <body bgcolor="black">
    <form method="get" action ="http://localhost:2013">
      <center>
        <font color="white" size=65>Enter Word: <input type="text" name="word"></font>
      </center>
      </br>
      <center>
        <font color="Green" size=65>
          <input type="submit" value="SUBMIT">
        </font>
      </center>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Any help will be of great help.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why is your HTML all in one line? Also, `<font>` and `<center>` are deprecated.

Comment: There *isn't any* default text in that code.

Comment: i am not an HTML expert i just need to test one bug. So need that kind of example. You modify whatever you want and give the reaped result i'll be thankful for you

Comment: -1 for reposting and hiding the fact you already got an answer

Comment: even though it is similar to his previous post, in this one hes asking how to make default text disappear with clicking rather than typing.
also he wants javascript.

Comment: yes...guys i am new to this stuff how to call js in html

Comment: i did it...now please upvote me ...i got to know abt discipline at stackoverflow and how to ask for your problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Complete code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title> - jsFiddle demo</title>

  <script type='text/javascript' src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js'></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/normalize.css">


  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/result-light.css">

  <style type='text/css'>
    input { color:#333; }

input:focus { color:#ccc;transition:color .2s linear 0;
              -webkit-transition:color .2s linear 0;
    -moz-transition:color .2s linear 0 }
input.typing { color:#333; }

  </style>



<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
$(window).load(function(){
$(function(){
    var input = $('input[name="word"]'), defaulttext = input.attr('data-default');

    input.val(input.attr('data-default'));

    input.on('focus', function(){
        if(input.val() != defaulttext)
            input.addClass('typing');
        else
            input.removeClass('typing');

    }).on('keydown', function(){        
        if(defaulttext == input.val()) input.val('');

        input.addClass('typing');
    }).on('blur', function(){
        if(input.val() == '') input.val(defaulttext);

        that.removeClass('typing');
    });


});

});//]]>  

</script>


</head>
<body bgcolor="black">
     <form method="get" action ="http://localhost:2013">
      <center>
        <font color="white" size=65>Enter Word: <input type="text" name="word" data-default="Default Text"></font>
      </center>
      </br>
      <center>
        <font color="Green" size=65>
          <input type="submit" value="SUBMIT">
        </font>
      </center>
    </form>

</body>


</html>
```

Comment: thankx for helping can i merger all this in one html file

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/d9CMR/186/

Comment: bro i want everything in one html page like this <FORM action="http://localhost:2013" method="post">
<INPUT type="text" size="25" value="Username" onFocus="if(this.value == 'Username') {this.value = '';}" onBlur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Username';}" />
<INPUT type=submit value=Submit>
</FORM>     how i'll integrate all these things in one file

Comment: that is one html page..just copy paste into text file and load into browser....i edited it into one page as you requested.

Comment: offcoz you deserve it.

Comment: need an amendment to below code, when i tested this code what happened is that when user clicks on submit button the default value it takes is a "username" and i want the value should get is a blank value below is the code"     <FORM action="http://localhost:2013" method="post">
<INPUT type="text" size="25" value="Username" onFocus="if(this.value == 'Username') {this.value = '';}" onBlur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Username';}" />
<INPUT type=submit value=Submit>
</FORM>

Comment: ask as a new question would be easier to answer there as its not related to the current question. ill answer over there.

Comment: ok...thanks a lot will update as new request

Comment: i answered that question, accept and upvote plz :P